# Could vs c̶o̶u̶l̶d̶n̶'̶t̶ may not?

Tags: could

I've seen situations in which they said these phrases:

1. **"[...] That could be dead or may not be"** (Jim Carrey's phrase in a Series of Unfortunate events)
2. **"(=if we had one, it could or it may not be expensive)"** (a specific grammar book by Cambridge University).

My question is: why "may" is opposed to "could" here? Can't we use "It could be dead or could not be" or "It could or it could not be expensive"? Why/why not?

Comment: You could say, "It could be dead or could not be," or you could not. "Could" implies that something could not be, so in a way, "could or could not be" is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Because *could not* does not mean *may not*. If you say *"it could not be dead,"* it means that it is definitely alive. If you say *"it may not be dead,"* it means there is a possibility that it is alive.

It's better to say *"may or may not be"* in these situations, but if you're speaking and have already said *could be*, it's good to switch verbs<sup>1</sup>—so I can understand why the scriptwriters had Jim Carrey say it. But if the grammar book is suggesting that you use this phrase instead of *may or may not be*, I would look for another grammar book.

<sup>1</sup> Although if you're speaking and say *"could or could not be"*, people will usually understand what you mean.

Comment: See [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=may+or+may+not+be%2Cmight+or+might+not+be%2Ccould+or+could+not+be+&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmay%20or%20may%20not%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmight%20or%20might%20not%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20or%20could%20not%20be%3B%2Cc0): *may or may not be* is 100 times more frequent than *could or could not be*.